# Get restaurant match percentage from Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-oauth

When using Google maps personally I see that it gives me a "match" percentage when I search nearby restaurants. Is there a way to access this information through the API after a user authorizes with their Google account OAuth sign-in?

I have dug around in the [https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro](Google Places API docs) but unable to find anything on restaurant match suggestions. Has anyone had experience using or seeing this in a response?

Thank you for any help in advance, I'm new to using Google APIs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get this information through the Maps APIs at this time.

However, you can file a Feature Request for this in Google's Public Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com

The Places API component can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188872)

Hope this helps!